# Is there a way to add constraints to a neural network output but still with softmax activation function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am not a deep learning geek, i am learning to do this for my homework.
How can I make my neural network output a list of positive floats that sum to 1 but at the same time each element of the list is smaller than a treshold (0.4 for example)?

I tried to add some hidden layers before the output layer but that didn't improve the results.
here is where i started from:

```
def build_net(inputs, predictor,scope,trainable):
    with tf.name_scope(scope):
        if predictor == 'CNN':
            L=int(inputs.shape[2])
            N = int(inputs.shape[3])
            conv1_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,L,N,32], stddev=0.15), trainable=trainable)
            layer = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, filter=conv1_W, padding='VALID', strides=[1, 1, 1, 1])
            norm1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)
            x = tf.nn.relu(norm1)

            conv3_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 32, 1], stddev=0.15), trainable=trainable)
            conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, filter=conv3_W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
            norm3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv3)
            net = tf.nn.relu(norm3)

            net=tf.layers.flatten(net)

            return net




x=build_net(inputs,predictor,scope,trainable=trainable)
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None]+[self.M])

network = tf.add(x,y)
w_init=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.0005,0.0005) 
outputs=tf.layers.dense(network,self.M,activation=tf.nn.softmax,kernel_initializer=w_init)
```

I am expecting that outputs would still sum to 1, but each element of it is smaller than a specific treshold i set.

Thank you so much in advance for your precious help guys.

Comment: Please your more code. I need to know what is the `network` and `self.M`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I added more code, self.M is the number of outputs i want.

Comment: Would be interesting to hear what the use case here is (i.e. why do you need numbers < 0.4), as it stands I find it difficult to imagine why/how you would do this.

Comment: 0.4 here is an exemple but not the exact treshold, i want to set them less than that because it is actually required :'( in order to build a correct model for the task, i need my outputs to be less than that treshold but still sum to 1 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is add a penalty in case any of the outputs is larger than some specified `thresh`, you can do this with the `max` function:

```
thresh = 0.4
strength = 10.0
reg_output = strength * tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.maximum(0.0, outputs - thresh), axis=-1)
```

Then you need to add `reg_output` to your loss so its optimized with the rest of the loss. `strength` is a tunable parameter that defines how strong is the penalty for going over the threshold, and you have to tune it to your needs.

This penalty works by summing `max(0, output - thresh)` over the last dimension, which activates the penalty if `output` is bigger than `thresh`. If its smaller, the penalty is zero and does nothing.